# Overriding Devise::Mailer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I'm attempting to override devise's mailer, per this [guide on using custom mailers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-custom-mailer).

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb

config.mailer = "AccountsMailer"
```

Really, I want to set the host dynamically for all mailer actions. But at the moment, it seems just a basic override of the `reset_password_instructions` method isn't even working.

```
# app/mailers/accounts_mailer.rb

class AccountsMailer < Devise::Mailer
  # allow use of before_filter
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  def default_url_options
    { host: 'overridden.com' }
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
    raise 'overridden'
    @host = 'overridden.co'
    super
  end

end
```

This makes me question if devise is even using my custom mailer.

```
# views/customers/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb

<% puts "*Mail View*" %>
<% puts @host  %>
<% puts Devise.mailer %>
...
```

From my forman log when this message is sent:

```
mailer.1  | *Mail View*
mailer.1  |
mailer.1  | AccountsMailer
mailer.1  | Render customers/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
```

So, Devise claims to be using AccountsMailer, but the method override isn't working, since the message is sent instead of en exception being raised, ...

---

#### Relevant Setup

- Rails 3.2.13
- Ruby 1.9.3-p374
- Devise 2.1.2
- Devise-async 0.5.1
- Sidekiq 2.12.0
- Foreman 0.61.0

  - web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
  - db: postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
  - redis: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
  - mailcatcher: mailcatcher -f
  - worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q high,2 -q default -e development -c 1
  - mailer: bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer -e development -c 1

#### Disclaimers

- Yes, I restarted foreman / my server
- I can't statically set the `action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]` in `environments/<env>.rb`, as the hostname is dynamic based on the type of user (staff and customers have different subdomains)

  - `action_mailer.default_url_options` doesn't accept a proc or block yet
- Setting host name in each view is too WET for me to sleep well

An SO search didn't seem to see anyone else with this issue, nor did devise GH issues -- so what am I overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this ended up being a version issue.

The documentation I was reading on the `devise` and `devise-async` pages was referencing current behavior. I was using 2.1.x and 0.5.x, respectively.

In those versions, overriding a mailer had to be done explicitly with `devise-async` using `config.mailer` (which I wasn't doing). As of 2.2.x and 0.7.x, `devise-async` uses `Devise.mailer` implicitly.

I've  upgraded to 2.2.x and 0.7.x and this solved the issue with the above code.

> **Note:** If you upgrade to 2.2.x from <= 2.1.x, note the backwards-incompatible changes introduced in 2.2

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! This was driving me mad all of Friday and this finally sorted it out :)